# How to fix khmer font on ios device with wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, fonts

My wordpress website having troble with khmer font showing wrong on ios device.

i'm tried to change font Khmer but it not work. but i use defualt divi theme font i work find.

Comment: Please make sure that you order yourself according to the appropriate guidelines as a good question is asked on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need embed Khmer font into your website, you can use Google web font: https://fonts.google.com/?subset=khmer

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Battambang&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Or include the font and use CSS3 to embed it

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but hope this will help those who finally arrived here.

As @Osify suggested, the best way to have Khmer font displayed correctly on your WordPress website is to use web-fonts, like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=khmer).

Some Khmer fonts from Google render correctly in the majority of devices and browsers. However, some not.

Some fonts namely, Moul or Nokora will render incorrectly when you browse your WordPress website on Safari of an iPhone 6 or later.

I would recommend you to switch to other fonts like 'Hanuman', 'Battambong', and 'Content' which will fix your problem.

**Plus**

For speed improvement, I'd suggest hosting those fonts locally as your website asset. A tool like [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) is the best assistant when working with Khmer Fonts.

[image]

The tool provides all the needed font files in all formats along with options to choose from and then generates the CSS font-face ready to use.